# Difference of two Gamma random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d Gamma random variables with a integer parameter $\alpha$, i.e, $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha,1)$.

I wish to find the density of $X-Y$, however the integrals are turning out be messy. Can anyone help me in this?

My actual goal is to compute the asymptotics of the entropy of $X-Y$ as $\alpha$ becomes large, where $h(Z)=\int f(z) \log \frac{1}{f(z)} dz$ is the entropy of any random variable with density $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the shape parameter $\alpha$ is large and the rate/scale parameter $\beta = 1$ is fixed, the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are approximately normal with mean and variance both equal to $\alpha$.  Therefore, their difference $W = X-Y$ is approximately normal with mean $0$ and variance $2\alpha$, with PDF $$f_W(w) \approx \frac{e^{-w^2/(4\alpha)}}{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}.$$  Then $$\operatorname{E}[-\log f(W)] \approx \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{W^2}{4\alpha} + \frac{1}{2} \log 4\pi \alpha\right] = \frac{1}{2}\log 4 \pi \alpha + \frac{1}{4\alpha}(\operatorname{Var}[W] + \operatorname{E}[W]^2) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \log 4\pi \alpha),$$ which is the asymptotic behavior of the entropy for large $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to the question about the density of the difference of two Gamma random variables can be found in [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48424/6633) on stats.SE.  As noted
there, in the general case, the integrals are not straightforward to evaluate. In the special case above when
the random variables are i.i.d. and the order parameter $\alpha$ is an
integer as in the OP's case, the integrals are still not easy but
have been studied before. Related integrals are
listed in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, *Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products,* Section 3.383, and the density can be determined from
these.